# What should I use as hostname to connect to mysql server from another computer?

Tags: mysql, hostname

I set up a mySQL server on my pc. Now I'd like to access some databases from another pc using mysql.connector in python using this connection string:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='HOSTNAME',user='USERNAME',password='PASSWORD',database='DATABASE')
```

But I don't really know what to use as a hostname in my connection string. I think it's supposed to be the IP address of the host computer. but should it be the external IP I found on whatismyip.com? (The host pc is connected to the internet through a router) Or the internal (static) IP? Or some combination of both.

Right now both the host pc and the one I'm trying to use to connect to it with are on the same network, but eventually I'd like to be able to connect to it from anywhere.

I'm really new to this stuff and haven't done anything like this before. All I can find on the internet is to use 'localhost' or 'use your IP address'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The `ip` address of your host, you can find this using `ifconfig` on the target machine.

Comment: You mean ipconfig.

Comment: @Octo: I think he meant **`ifconfig`** for linux or unix. On Microsoft Windows, use **`ipconfig`**.

Comment: @Octo: sorry after eight years of detoxing from Windows, one forgets it's still around.

Comment: Is this server on a private network behind a NAT (most computers are this way) or is the IP address actually visible on the internet? If on the internet, is it in a registered DNS domain? You may need to configure your NAT/Firewall to forward a port to this server and then it would have both a private internal network name and a public internet name.

Answer (score 1):

Given the are somehow connected, and can "*see each other*" you can enter the ip address of the other computer. You can look this up using `ifconfig`. A sample output of `ifconfig` looks like:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:5e:0f:1e:00:55  
        inet addr:192.168.123.114  Bcast:192.168.123.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::7a7c:eed1:6a9c:e246/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:216736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:131666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:256313024 (256.3 MB)  TX bytes:63599510 (63.5 MB)
```

Comment: What if they are not connected? Two computers on totally different networks, just connected to the internet?

Comment: Well it depends, if the are both behind a NAT router, the can't connect to each other. Otherwise have to look up their global IP to find out how to connect. If they are simply not connected to each other at all, it is impossible to query the database: how would you contact someone if you have no common communication channel?

Comment: Right now they are, but they are both connected to the same router.

Comment: Well as said before if they are connected to the same router, you can look up the ip address of the one with the database server and put that one in your config.